# Need to create and return unordered list in PHP class

Tags: php, function, class

I am trying to create a list like the following one:

```
<option value="1">Location 1</option>
<option value="2">Location 2</option>
<option value="3">Location 3</option>
```

the Public Function in the class should fetch all values from DB to output the results in the format shown above. Here is my function:

```
public function FitArea(){
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `delivery_cost` ORDER BY 'id'");

    $sth->execute();

    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $FitLocation = array("id" => $row["id"], "location" => $row["location"], "cost" => $row["cost"]);

    return $FitLocation;

}
```

obviously I am calling the class first on the page, but I am not sure if I am doing the rest correctly as nothing simply happens.

```
    <?php
    require_once("class/class.get.materials.php");
$getMaterials =  new Getmaterials();
    $FitLocation = $getMaterials->FitArea();
    while($FitLocation > 0){
    print<<<END
    <option value="{$FitLocation['cost']}">{$FitLocation['location']}</option>
    END;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes it does, I have just updated my question as I simply forgot to add it the code that I posted here

Comment: `ORDER BY 'id'` there shouldn't be quotes, it's a column, not a string.

Comment: Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll see that heredoc is going to complain. See => http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc - should that be your actual code.

Comment: I have, but no errors that I can refer to, I even tried 'print_r();' and the only thing I have there is the firs row from DB

Comment: It just keeps crashing firefox browser on every refresh too

Comment: There was no reason at all for marking my question or my answer  as not useful as could have been useful for me and may come in useful for somebody else out there

Comment: what are you talking about? any messages you post here, I get notification, since I'm the only one who commented.

Comment: Sorry, made an error posting it into the wrong place, my apologies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just got it to work, for newbies like myself, here is my detailed answer:

the Public Function should look like the following:

```
public function FitArea(){
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `delivery_cost` ORDER BY id");

    $sth->execute();

    $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $FitLocation = array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){
        array_push($FitLocation,
            array(
                "id" => $row[$i]["id"],
                "location" => $row[$i]["location"],
                "cost" => $row[$i]["cost"],
            )
        );

    }

    return $FitLocation;

}
```

and the rest should be as follows:

```
<?php
require_once("class/class.get.materials.php");
$getMaterials =  new Getmaterials();
$FitLocation = $getMaterials->FitArea();
foreach($FitLocation as $key => $value){
print<<<END
<option value="{$value['cost']}">{$value['location']}</option>
END;
}
?>
```

All and all, it feels great when you can figure it out all by yourself

Thanks to all